# Facebook Authentication on Blackberry

Tags: java, facebook, blackberry

Hey all, I've been checking out the Facebook BB SDK, find it to be a little bit complicated and not being able to debug it for some reason doesn't really help my comprehension of it. The use I need of this is quite limited since I only wanna be able to post to FB as status update and besides that just require the permissions.

On the BB side all I want to do is get the authorization token and sent it over to be persisted, now, how can i log back on to FB using only that token ? because I don't wanna prompt the user again for his credentials each time he wants to do a FB update. I also found that the tokens have an expire date on them, is there a way to work around this, would appreciate if anyone who has worked with the SDK would give me a hand on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've gotten a little more understanding of how it works and created a FB app on my account, now i have my own keys and ID and I tested them using the strawberry app provided with the SDK. I wanna know how people use the SDK, because I've read that they build their app over it in some cases :S and the function i need from it is very limited, any help will do

Comment: No one? This really has me stumped because if I add the files I need for my project the project won't build properly, and it apparently has to do with the amount of files I have. And if i set the FacebokSDK as a referenced library my App will demand to also have installed the sample App bundled with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add permission "offline_access" when u login, token return with expire=0.